# Delegate.DynamicInvoke too slow, how to change call to Invoke?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, dynamic, delegates, invoke

I've read that i should create and reuse delegates to get the value of a property of an object.

I use this code to create the Delegate

```
    var objParm = Expression.Parameter(property.DeclaringType, "o");

    Type delegateType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(property.DeclaringType, property.PropertyType);

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda(delegateType, Expression.Property(objParm, property.Name), objParm);

    return lambda.Compile()
```

Now i only find the way to use the delegate in the call of "DynamicInvoke".

Now i want to change the call to "invoke" cause of performance reasons.

I tried

```
Delegate.Method.Invoke(invokedObject, null);
```

But after the call i get the exception

```
MethodInfo must be a RuntimeMethodInfo.
```

I have an cache class for each property where i can store the dynamically created delegate.

What should i do so i am able to use "normal" Invokes?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: "I've read that i should create and reuse delegates to get the value of a property of an object." In very rare cases this is correct, "very" being the operative word here. Most of the time you should just you `x.Property`.

Comment: Yes your're totally right, was my mistake in the explanation. Was meant in coherency with reflection (GetValue, SetValue).

Comment: The problem here is that not only does the name of the property vary at runtime, but so does the type.  This is forcing you to use a slow reflection-based invoke instead of a fast type-safe delegate call.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've created a class that I use when I need to access properties by using their name as text. The class caches all properties for an class.

Usage:

```
PropertyWrapper<User> wrapper = new PropertyWrapper<User>();
wrapper.SetValue("FirstName", "arne");
int age = (int)wrapper.GetValue("Age");
```

The class

```
public class PropertyWrapper<T>
{
    private Dictionary<string, Methods> _properties = new Dictionary<string, Methods>();
    private class Methods
    {
        public MethodBase Get { get; set; }
        public MethodBase Set { get; set; }
    }

    public PropertyWrapper()
    {
        foreach (var item in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        {
            if (!item.CanRead && !item.CanWrite)
                continue;

            var mappings = new Methods();
            if (item.CanRead)
                mappings.Get = item.GetGetMethod();
            if (item.CanWrite)
                mappings.Set = item.GetSetMethod();

            _properties.Add(item.Name, mappings);
        }
    }

    public object GetValue(T instance, string name)
    {
        Methods mappings;
        if (_properties.TryGetValue(name, out mappings) && mappings.Get != null)
            return mappings.Get.Invoke(instance, null);

        throw new MappingException("Specified property cannot be read", typeof(T), name);
    }

    public void SetValue(T instance, string name, object value)
    {
        Methods mappings;
        if (_properties.TryGetValue(name, out mappings) && mappings.Set != null)
        {
            mappings.Set.Invoke(instance, new[] { value });
            return;
        }

        throw new MappingException("Specified property cannot be written.", typeof(T), name);
    }
}

public class MappingException : Exception
{
    public MappingException(string errMsg, Type type, string propertyName) 
        : base(errMsg)
    {
        ReflectedType = type;
        PropertyName = propertyName;
    }

    public Type ReflectedType { get; private set; }
    public string PropertyName { get; private set; } 
}
```

Comment: This is still slow.  To get high performance, you need to make `mappings.Set(instance, value)` work (i.e. no untyped parameter array).

Answer (score 6):

You would have to emit a `Func<object,object>` delegate instead, and cast as necessary inside the lambda and when retrieving the result.  If you do not know the type of the delegate at compile time, you cannot invoke it directly, since you don't know what kind of arguments it takes, nor what the return type will be.

Also, note that you could just be creating a delegate around `property.GetGetMethod()` -- there is no reason to compile your own method here.  Just use the property getter method.

Comment: thanks for the hint, mark the answer of jgauffin cause of the nice code ;)